# How to use keyboard input parameter in docker-compose?

Tags: docker-compose, keyboard-input

I need to start windows *docker-compose* include keyboard input properties.

I use bat file:

```
set /p u="user: "
set /p p="pass: "
docker-compose up
```

and include docker-compose.yml:

```
environment:
      - user=%u%
      - pas=%p%
```

but it's not working.

How to use keyboard input parameter in *docker-compose*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to use it as described below

bat file:

```
set /p u="user: "
set USER="%u%"
set /p p="pass: "
set PASS="%p%"
docker-compose up
```

docker-compose.yml

```
environment:
 - user=$USER
 - pas=$PASS
```